# problem in unordered_map iterator implementation with const

Tags: c++, hashmap, iterator, unordered-map

This is probably a really stupid question, but I've been thinking for some time now, and haven't figured out the solution to the problem. Any help would be appreciated.
I've been trying to write a basic version of c++ `std::unordered_map`, and have trouble with implementing the iterator. For convenience, here are only the methods which are causing the problem, it is not a full implementation:

```
template<class Key, class Val>
class UnorderedMap {
public:

    ... 

    void Erase(const Key & k) {
        // needs to erase key, value from somewhere in hash_table, 
        // calls std::erase() on it or similar
    }

    ...

    class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, std::pair<Key, Val>> {
    public:
        Iterator(std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<Key, Val>>> * hash_table_ptr,
                 size_t bucket_idx, size_t collision_idx): hash_table_ptr(hash_table_ptr),
                 bucket_idx(bucket_idx), collision_idx(collision_idx) {
        }

        std::pair<const KeyType, Val>& operator *() {
            return (*hash_table_ptr)[bucket_idx][collision_idx]; // this doesn't compile
        }

        std::pair<const KeyType, Val> * operator ->() {
            return &(*(*this));
            // not sure about this, but I think that this works
        }

        Iterator& operator ++();

        ...

    private:
        int bucket_idx, collision_idx;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<Key, Val>>> * hash_table_ptr;

    };

    Iterator Begin() {
        return iterator(&hash_table_, 0, 0);
    }

    Iterator End() {
        return iterator(&hash_table_, hash_table.size(), 0);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<Key, Val>>> hash_table;
    ...
};
```

Basically, an element of hash_table is a list of all pairs {key, value}, where hash(key) is the same (just list of all the collisions). So, in order to implement the iterator, in the class, I keep the bucket_index(points to the vector of pairs), and the collision_index(points to exactly on which pair are we), also, the pointer to the hash_table(doesn't matter to us that it may invalidate after reallocation).

Now, to the actual problem:

Operator * in the iterator class needs to return `std::pair<const Key, Val>&`. If I keep the pairs in hash_table as `std::pair<Key, Val>`,as it is in the code, then the compiler is unable to transform this to `std::pair<const Key, Val>` in any way, I think.(Complier, for example,  gives error  error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::__cxx11::basic_string >&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::__cxx11::basic_string >)

If, on the other hand, I keep the the pairs in hash_table as `std::pair<const Key, Val>`, then I won't be able to call std::erase on it, or similar functions, which I also need.
The reason why std::erase doesn't work can be illustrated in a simple example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<const int, int>> vec = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};    
vec.erase(vec.begin());
```

This gives error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const int, int>& std::pair<const int, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const int, int>&)’
*__result = std::move(*__first);

I know that this question is probably more related to c++ syntax rather then std::unordered_map 's implementation, but maybe, for example, keeping a pointer to the hash_table in the iterator class is incorrect, so, i'm leaving the structure of the class for clarity.

Comment: "If, on the other hand, I keep the the pairs in hash_table as std::pair<const Key, Val>, then I won't be able to call std::erase on it" Why is that? Please show actual code and relevant error messages.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Edited the post with error messages

Comment: You are going to have to use placement new and the like I suspect.

Comment: The conclusion is that `std::vector` is not a suitable backing store for an `std::unordered_map`-like container implementation. `std::unordered_map` is meant to be a node-based container.

Comment: Such erase would invalidate pointers and references to existing elements, so you cannot implement  std::unordered_map this way.